# A question about a linear algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider following statement:

Every positive operator $T:V\to V$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional complex innner product space has a unique positive square root.

The proof in my notes is this: use previous theorems to write $V$ as direct sum of eigen spaces for eigenvalues of $T$, to get existence of square root $S$ and to write $V$ as direct sum of eigen spaces of $S$. Etc.

It is not so long. But I wonder if it could be proved like this: (can you tell me if following is a valid proof?)

On complex vector spaces $V$ every operator $T$ has an eigen basis. Represented in the eigen basis $T$  is a diagonal matrix $D$. Then $S=\sqrt{D}$ is a square root of $T$. By assumption $T$ is positive and therefore has only non negative real eigen values. Therefore $S$ is a positive square root.

Please can you tell me if this is a valid proof of the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence of your "proof" is wrong. And you certainly haven't argued uniqueness at all.

Comment: Fairly sure $T$ is supposed to be assumed positive in which case $T$ does have an eigenbasis; no?

Comment: Yes, but the OP said *every* operator. This particular result takes the spectral theorem and some work to prove uniqueness.

Comment: Sorry, I meant every positive operator. Is it valid then? And doesn't uniqueness follow from uniqueness of square root?

Comment: Well, so you're following the proof they suggested, quoting the Spectral Theorem for hermitian operators. No, I'm not convinced by your uniqueness claim. Why couldn't I come up with a different operator in some way? In particular, your construction depends on a particular choice of basis, which may be far from unique.

Comment: Is it not possible to prove a following modified spectral theorem: Every self-adjoint operator has a unique orthonormal eigen basis. ?

Comment: No, it's definitely not possible. There are two problems: (1) Eigenspaces may be more than $1$-dimensional, in which case there are very many choices (given by the unitary group $U(k)$ if the subspace is $k$-dimensional); (2) Even if eigenspaces are $1$-dimensional, you can vary your unit vector spanning it by multiplying by $e^{i\theta}$, so there's a circle's worth of unit vectors (this is compatible with my comment in case (1) — it's $U(1)$ in this case).

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful! I finally understand!!